# Realtime way to detect push notifcation is enable or not in swift (Combine publisher)

Tags: ios, swift, combinelatest

I have a function that checks whether the user has enabled their push notification/ notification alert in the iphone. If the user has turned on their notification, it will print true in the swift view, and if the user has turned off their notification, it will print false.

I could achieve this using the stated below function and gives relevant output. But, this is not real-time. I have to close and re-open the app to reflect current changes. Im looking way to give true/false real-time and async using publisher and subscriber which show status realtime in my app

My code :-

```
var isRegister : Bool = false
    func isEnabled() -> Bool {
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.getNotificationSettings { (settings) in

        if(settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized) {
            isRegister = true
            print("Push notification is enabled")
        } else {
            isRegister = false
            print("Push notification is not enabled")
        }
    }
    return isRegister
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are a delay in getting authorization status of notification

so you should have to use completion

```
    func authorizeStatus(completion: @escaping (_ isAuthorized: Bool) -> Void) {
       let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
       center.getNotificationSettings { (settings) in

           if(settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized) {
               completion(true)
               print("Push notification is enabled")
           } else {
               completion(false)
               print("Push notification is not enabled")
           }
      }
   }
```

and how to check

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        authorizeStatus { isAuthorized in
            print(isAuthorized)
        }
    }
```

and if you want check status when click on Allow or Cancel of Notification Alert you can check it as follow

```
 UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [ .sound, .badge]) { (success, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Request Authorization Failed (\(error), \(error.localizedDescription))")
             }
             else{
             print(success) // check here
                if success {
                   print("you enable it")
                } else {
                   print("you cancel it")
                }
              }
           }
```

how to check in swift ui

```
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            .onAppear { self. authorizeStatus { isAuthorized in
                            print(isAuthorized)
                       }
             }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I really appreciate for answering it. But this is not going to give me real-time changes right. I need to do an app restart. Also, I'm looking for a solution in swiftUI

Comment: just call it on onAppear {}

Comment: this real time I think

Answer (score 0):

how to check in swift ui

```
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            .onAppear { self. authorizeStatus { isAuthorized in
                            print(isAuthorized)
                       }
             }
 }
```

Im trying to add text componenet to display text in my app. These solution does display in the log of xcode but no in the app. There is no way to use Text() as its bool value.

Any way to display text message on the screen directly and in the realtime